# On scroll, ListView items out of the screens change background

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a `ListView` to display a list of countries. For each alphabet,I have a row containing the letter, just to make the `ListView` more clear (so it looks like this : 'A', then Austria, Australia ... then 'B' then Belgium, Bolivia etc ... ).

For the rows with the letter, I set the clickable and the enabled attribute to false. I also change the background and the textcolor. Everything is perfect on the first sight, but as soon as I start scrolling, the rows out of the screens start to exchange their attribute: some countries rows take the Letter rows attribute, and some letter rows turn to country raw. It only happens with the items outside of the screen, so not visible. Here is my code:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> nonFocusableElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//THE COUNTRIES ARE ALREADY SORTED ON THE QUERY. I CHECK THE FIRST LETTER AND A ROW TO SEPARATE THE COUNTRIES BY LETTER
        Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery(query, null);
        String firstCharacter = " ";
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String[] values = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int i = 0;
            do {
                if (!cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("country_name")).substring(0, 1).equals(firstCharacter)) {
                    firstCharacter = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("country_name")).substring(0, 1);
                    values = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length + 1);
                    values[i] = firstCharacter;
                    nonFocusableElements.add(i);
                    i++;
                }
                values[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("country_name"));
                i++;

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            sql.close();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        ;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////   post() ensure that listview is RENDERED     /////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

// HERE I MANAGE THE LETTER'S ROW

```
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if(!rendered) {
                int visiblesElements = listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = 0; i < nonFocusableElements.size(); i++) {
                    if (listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)) != null) {
                        listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)).setEnabled(false);
                        listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)).setClickable(false);
                        listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)).setFocusable(false);
                        listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)).setOnClickListener(null);
                        listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AFAFAF"));

                        TextView text = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(nonFocusableElements.get(i)).findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    rendered=true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

//LISTENER FOR THE COUNTRY ROWS

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("type", "state");
            bundle.putString("value", ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString());
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            AlphabeticalListViewFragment liste = new AlphabeticalListViewFragment();
            liste.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, liste, "listfragment");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(liste.getClass().getName());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Do you know what is wrong here? Thanks. I add that I tried many solutions found on SO but nothing is working for me...

Comment: Please use a custom adapter for ListView.

Comment: Is it the only solution? As an android beginner I would be glad to find a simple way to fix this without having to create a custom adapter...

Comment: Its realy simple.Please go through some tutorials.

Comment: but just, are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: Android ListView use Adapters to recycle views that's why ListView position changes while scrolling to conserve memory.See the Google I/O presentation given by Romain Guy to understand how adapters work. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

Also check the below links,

http://strangevikas.wordpress.com/tag/how-adapter-works-in-android-android-and-adapters/

http://www.edureka.in/blog/what-are-adapters-in-android/

Comment: I will use a custom adapter then. thanks.